# Is it possible to get rid of successful deployment checks at Google App Engine?

Tags: google-app-engine

While deploying a local GAE app via `appcfg.py`, it makes checks if the deployment is successful, like:

```
Will check again in 32 seconds.
Checking if deployment succeeded.
```

Is it possible to get rid of these checks, or decrease the number of checks (e.g stop at 4 seconds)? I understand that these checks are probably necessary and that I may be trying to defeat the sheer purpose, but I'm curious if it's possible.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think so. Deployment follows a strict procedure. After the successful deployment your cron scripts, indexes are uploaded/built. It's a one way procedure and makes total sense to 1st check if the deployment was successful and then update,build indexes, cron script's and any other thing that, I am not aware of.